# Python: Cleaning up string to insert in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, hex, byte, decode

I download random city names using python to insert in a mysql table after.
The problem is that sometimes it gets hex characters in the middle of the string, for example: `PÄ±narbaÅ\x9fÄ±` and `PÅ\x82ock` and `RÃ\xado IbÃ¡Ã±ez`.

Because of the slash '' for the hex, it causes issue with the INSERT clauses of mysql.
I tried to decode with `bytes()`, `str()` and `decode()` functions from Python but could not get it to work.

What is the best approach for that?

Comment: Almost certainly the answer is to use a prepared statement, but without seeing your actual code it's hard to be completely sure.

Comment: ok, maybe it is not the best approach but I solved by removing those characters from my string. I will soon publish my project in github and will link it here.